# Two different methods for reversing an array of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, reverse

So I've been trying to reverse an array of strings in c, My first method returns a segmentation fault:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *states[100], *temp[100];
    int i,j=0,n;
    printf("no of states");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    n=j;
    printf("enter the states");
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        scanf("%s",&states[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("%s",states[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        for(j=n-1;j>i;j--){
            temp[i]=states[i];
            states[i]=states[j];
            states[j]=temp[i];

        }
    }

}
```

My second try resulted in a assignment to array type error

```c
typedef struct states
{
    char states[100];
}states;

main()
{
    states st[2],temp[2];
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the number of states");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    n=j;
    printf("Enter the states");
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        scanf("%s",st[i].states);
    }
    for(i=0;i<j;i++){
        for(n=j;n<i;n--){
            temp[i].states=st[i].states;
            st[i].states=st[n].states;
            st[n].states=temp[i].states;
        }
    }
}
```

My idea is to accept three states. For example `"Texas,Illinois,Oregon"` and then return `"Oregon,Illinois,Texas"`.

Comment: First of all, you've an array of 100 pointers each pointing to some garbage. You need to initalize each of them using `malloc` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems in your first code -

1. Uninitalized pointers -

   ```
   char *states[100], *temp[100];
   ```

2.This `scanf`-

```
 scanf("%s",&states[i]);
            ^not required
```

Now correct solution would be -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
 {
      char *states[100], *temp[100];
      int i,j=0,n;
      printf("no of states");
      scanf("%d",&j);
       n=j;
      printf("enter the states\n");
     for (i=0;i<j;i++){
          states[i]=malloc(100);         //allocating memory to pointer 
          scanf("%99s",states[i]);
     }

    for(i=0,j=n-1;i<j;j--,i++){

        temp[i]=malloc(100);                   // allocating memory to pointer
        strcpy(temp[i],states[i]);               //swapping the strings
        strcpy(states[i],states[j]); 
        strcpy(states[j],temp[i]);

   }
     j=n;               //set j=n 
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
             printf("%s\n",states[i]);
             free(states[i]);                 //free allocated memory
             free(temp[i]);                   //free memory
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I choose to go with two different for loops for i and j in the main swapping block,I get erroneous results. Any help

Comment: @Identical  Well two different loops are not required. As also increase complexity .

Comment: @Identical  But you got wrong results because inner `for loop` continuous until `j=i` and then stop but till then `i` is same . Lets see for 1st iteration `i=0` and now inner loop `j=n-1` **swap** , then again inner loop `j--` i.e  `j=n-2` and `i` is same , thus again swapping until `j` becomes equal to `i`.

Comment: @Identical  As inner loop ends you end up swapping index `0` and `1` , where you needed to swap index `0` and `n-1` .  After this inner loop ends `i` becomes `1` and inner loop starts again with `j=n-1` ,thus again wrong swapping . Similarly for all iteration your loops swap wrong indexs giving you wrong results .

Answer (score 0):

There is lot of mistakes in your code, understand the concepts of string & char properly.

following is the working code for your problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
typedef struct states
{
    char states[100];
}states;

main()
{
    int i,n;
    printf("Enter the number of states");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    states st[n],temp;
    printf("Enter the states");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s",st[i].states);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n/2;i++){
        temp=st[i];
        st[i]=st[n-i-1];
        st[n-i-1]=temp;
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%s",st[i].states);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on your first try.

To reverse the strings the logic is quite simple we just assign values to the temp from the behind like in the code. Use `strcpy` to copy strings instead of `=`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char states[20][20],temp[20][20];//Taking maximum 20 states
    int i,j=0,n;
    printf("no of states");
    scanf("%d",&j);
    n=j;
    printf("enter the states");
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        scanf("%s",states[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("%s,",states[i]);
    }

    //Reversing the states
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        strcpy(temp[n-i-1],states[i]);
    }
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        strcpy(states[i],temp[i]);
    }

    printf("\nReversed States: ");
    for (i=0;i<j;i++){
        printf("%s,",states[i]);
    }

}
```